# array from android java

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, array-map

I am making an application where I have String which behaves like Array.

> e.g : String name = " "john","kat" ";

I was trying to send them in php server(just sending the string wasn't converting it to array).

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $names=array($_POST['name']);
    $phones=array($_POST['phone']);
   // $names = array("Hw", "V");
   // $phones = array("656", "646");
    
    array_map(function ($name, $phone) {
     
include '../connection.php';
    $username=$_POST['username'];
        $insert = "INSERT INTO `contact`(`username`, `name`, `contact`) VALUES ('$username','$name','$phone')";
         if(mysqli_query($con,$insert)){
         }else{
         }
    }, $names, $phones);
    
}
?>
```

It was just inserting these not different strings

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPvn8.png)

I request not to comment about SQL Injections. I will work on it later.

```
private void readContacts(String username){
    Cursor c;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    c=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC ");
    int i=0;
    String name = "",contact_number="";
    while (c.moveToNext()){
        //get contact list
        String displayName=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String number=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        //put value into Hashmap
        HashMap<String, String> user_data = new HashMap<>();
        user_data.put(Constant.NAME, displayName);
        user_data.put(Constant.PHONE_NUMBER, number);
        list.add(user_data);


        if (name.isEmpty()){
            name = "\""+displayName+"\"";
        }else {
            name = name + ", " +"\""+ displayName+"\"";
        }

        if (contact_number.isEmpty()){
            contact_number = "\""+number+"\"";
        }else{
            contact_number = contact_number+ ", " +"\""+ number+"\"";
        }
    }

    Log.d("CONTACTS_NAME", String.valueOf(list));

    Log.d("COUNTS_CONTACTS",name);
    Log.d("CONTACTS_",contact_number);


    if (!name.isEmpty()){
        insertContacts(username,name,contact_number);
    }

    c.close();
}


private void insertContacts(String username,String name,String contactNumber){
    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Contacts> call = apiInterface.contact(username,name,contactNumber);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Contacts>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Contacts> call, Response<Contacts> response) {
//                String value = response.body().getValue();
//                String message = response.body().getMessage();

//                Log.d("value",value);
//                Log.d("message",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Contacts> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("ERROR",t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `And, If source code of Java needed I will add them..` 
Yes add It.  the java code will help us understand the issue.

Comment: @AmBen I have added..!